# Errors during factory reset on a device using encryption

Tags: factory-reset, system-error

Whenever factory reset is tried on device using encryption, the following error shows up:

```
wiping data...  
formatting /data...  
E:failed to mount /data (Invalid argument)  
E:format_volume failed to mount "/data"  
E:format_volume: wipe_data_without_wipe_media failed  
Formatting /cache...  
Data wipe failed.
```

What is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Solution is to format **/data + /data/media**.

If you ever wanted to do factory reset after using encryption, you need to format the entire `/data` partition.

What you have tried is formatting `/data` without deleting the contents of `/data/media`. This wouldn't work because this step tries to mount `/data` partition in recovery and then delete the contents of it without touching `/data/media`.

The primary reason for this error is the recovery cannot mount the encrypted `/data` partition.

So, its required to backup the contents of `/data/media` aka `Internal Storage` before every factory reset (formatting /data + /data/media) on device using encryption.